# How to order by date and keep unread messages on top?

Tags: django-rest-framework

I use django rest framework. I have a model message, with two attribute we care about :

- date_read
- date_created

Unread messages have date_read set to *NULL*. I want to order messages by date_created ASC and by date_read in order to keep unread messages on top.

Actual ordering I have by date_created

- ID - date_read - date_created
- 1 - 22/07 - 21/07
- 2 - NULL - 16/07
- 3 - 01/07 - 14/07
- 4 - NULL - 11/07

And what I want with unread messages on TOP :

- ID - date_read - date_created
- 2 - NULL - 16/07
- 4 - NULL - 11/07
- 1 - 22/07 - 21/07
- 3 - 01/07 - 14/07

Thanks you !

Comment: Isn't this in *descending* order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can order by two conditions, and use annotations to check if a value is null, like:

```
from django.db.models import BooleanField, ExpressionWrapper, Q

Message.objects.annotate(
    is_read=ExpressionWrapper(Q(date_read__isnull=False), BooleanField())
).order_by('is_read', '-date_created')
```

This will generate a query that looks like:

```
SELECT message.*, date_read IS NOT NULL AS is_read
FROM message
ORDER BY is_read ASC, date_created DESC
```